# Error in building itk with GDCM git repository

Tags: itk, gdcm

I build ITK with gdcm official release for windows. But its not having some of file that I'm using in further coding. So I have to use git version of gdcm cause its having those which I needed but following error encountered when I am trying to build ITK with ITK_USE_SYSTEM_GDCM and using gdcm git version to build gdcm bin.

```
>------ Build started: Project: ITKIOGDCM, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
80>Compiling...
80>itkGDCMImageIO.cxx
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMImageIO.cxx(41) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdcmImageHelper.h': No such file or directory
80>itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx
80>D:\ITK\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\include\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.h(154) : error C2664: 'void gdcm::SerieHelper::AddRestriction(const gdcm::TagKey &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::string' to 'const gdcm::TagKey &'
80>        Reason: cannot convert from 'const std::string' to 'const gdcm::TagKey'
80>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx(29) : error C2248: 'gdcm::SerieHelper::SerieHelper' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'gdcm::SerieHelper'
80>        D:\GDCM\gdcm\src\gdcmSerieHelper.h(198) : see declaration of 'gdcm::SerieHelper::SerieHelper'
80>        D:\GDCM\gdcm\src\gdcmSerieHelper.h(64) : see declaration of 'gdcm::SerieHelper'
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx(160) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'gdcm::File'
80>        D:\GDCM\gdcm\src\gdcmSerieHelper.h(34) : see declaration of 'gdcm::File'
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx(160) : error C2227: left of '->IsReadable' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx(163) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'gdcm::File'
80>        D:\GDCM\gdcm\src\gdcmSerieHelper.h(34) : see declaration of 'gdcm::File'
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx(163) : error C2227: left of '->GetFileName' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx(166) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'gdcm::File'
80>        D:\GDCM\gdcm\src\gdcmSerieHelper.h(34) : see declaration of 'gdcm::File'
80>..\..\..\..\..\src\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.cxx(166) : error C2227: left of '->GetFileName' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
80>itkGDCMImageIOFactory.cxx
80>Generating Code...
80>Build log was saved at "file://d:\ITK\binGDCM\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\ITKIOGDCM.dir\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
80>ITKIOGDCM - 9 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the very old and deprecated GDCM 1.x with GDCM 2.x. They are actually **API** incompatible.